# .NET MAUI Debugging: Mono.Android.AdbException

Tags: xamarin.android, maui

I try to debug clean MAUI/XAML app for Android with net6.0 on OPPO A15.

There is absolutely weird situation - application is build and deployed correctly (i can run it clicking on device screen) but i cannot debug it with below Xamarin diagnostics:

```
[D:RunShellCommand]:      192.168.0.64:5555 setprop "debug.mono.extra" ""
[E:RunShellCommand]:      192.168.0.64:5555 logcat -v time "dalvikvm:S" "ActivityThread:S" "mkestner:S" "MonoDroid-Debugger:S" failed: Mono.AndroidTools.AdbException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer()
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadLine()
   at Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbClient.ReadLineWhile(Action`1 output, Func`1 predicate) in D:\a\_work\1\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Adb\AdbClient.cs:line 585
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbClient.ReadLineWhile(Action`1 output, Func`1 predicate) in D:\a\_work\1\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Adb\AdbClient.cs:line 592
   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass119_0.<RunShellCommandAsync>b__0() in D:\a\_work\1\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\AndroidDevice.cs:line 1021
[E:RunShellCommand]:      192.168.0.64:5555 logcat -v time failed: Mono.AndroidTools.AdbException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer()
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadLine()
   at Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbClient.ReadLineWhile(Action`1 output, Func`1 predicate) in D:\a\_work\1\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Adb\AdbClient.cs:line 585
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbClient.ReadLineWhile(Action`1 output, Func`1 predicate) in D:\a\_work\1\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Adb\AdbClient.cs:line 592
   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass119_0.<RunShellCommandAsync>b__0() in D:\a\_work\1\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\AndroidDevice.cs:line 1021
```

But if i minimize app immediately after start (when .NET screen was shown and DLLs are loaded into app) and  maximize it after some time - it works perfectly...

Debug output finishes with below for invalid work:

```
[apitrace] apitrace: warning: caught signal 3
[apitrace] call flush from exceptionCallback
[apitrace] apitrace: info: taking default action for signal 3
```

Attempts:

- reinstall MAUI workload for VS
- reinstall Android SDK
- switch on/off Fast Deployment
- switch on/off XAML Hot Reload

On emulators it works fine.
Nobody has similar problems?

Thanks for help

Comment: Did you try  to test the project on the other kind of device or the emulator?

Comment: It works on HUAWEI DRA-LX9

Comment: So this is special device problem.